# change default storage to websocket connections

Tags: node.js, websocket

Здрайствуйте форумчаны!

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой веб сокетов и ее расширяемости.

Так вот **Предсавте ситуацию**

Вы разрабатываете сервер на Node js и вам нужно сделать несколько инстансов сервера
Как решить проблему связаную с тем, что у каждого с инстансов свой список соединений?
(Проблему решал использованием Redis pub/sub ) Хотелось бы найти более елегантное ришение типа изминение дефолтного storage connections у вебсокетов

Comment: [Первая ссылка в гугле](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzIcGhJC8hA), [Вторая ссылка в гугле](https://tsh.io/blog/how-to-scale-websocket/) . [Этот вариант мне понравился больше](https://blog.jscrambler.com/scaling-node-js-socket-server-with-nginx-and-redis/) . Более элегантного решения чем сессии найти вам не удастся. Используйте Редис `pub`/`sub` и все будет хорошо. Взгляните на ссылки, подчерпнете что-то новое.

Comment: Да, но хотелось бы какое то рeшение типа изменения дефолтного user connections storage на Redis например.